# mysql search/replace using string found within results to output new string

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Did an import from Drupal to Wordpress, and the Drupal content had a custom media block/module that contains garbled code to display an embedded YouTube video. It came into Wordpress looking like this:

`268103<br /> Pittsburgh Concert Society: Young Artists Concert Series - April 16, 2023 [livestream]<br /> youtube://v/YmY-b_OtCuc<br /> 1680282009<br />`

That string is in a custom field. So it came in, but it's not usable.

what I'd like to do is run a search/replace query to take that garbage and extract just the part after youtube://v/ and then insert that into a new entry in the same database field like this:

```
https://youtu.be/[extracted string]
```

search does find 33 entries in that garbled format, but converting them into a new string using a portion of the existing string is my challenge.

Comment: can you show what you tried and what happened?

Comment: I did a search of the database and found 33 entries but I don't know how to extract the data from the field and then replace the field contents with some of the data plus the opening URL string of https://youtu.be/

Comment: doesn't feel like you've spent much time looking for how to do this?  here's an example to start with: https://dbfiddle.uk/UCbApc8s